# Take back Ctrl-/ from Debian console configuration

Tags: bash, keyboard, debian, emacs, console

My Debian Testing console is stealing my Ctrl-/ and using it as Backspace; Ctrl-/ is the single key-press Undo in bash and emacs. After some research, it looks like the Ctrl-/ -> Backspace mapping might be a traditional, historical mapping on ancient Unix consoles, but hasn't been that way in any other Linux console I've used for almost 20 years[1].  I've spent lots of time looking in 'man keyboard' and other places and can't find the source of this (abnormally) traditional configuration and I'm hoping it's not a done through a kernel mod.

Any idea on what I have to tweak to get my Ctrl-/ back in the standard Debian console?

[1] Although, admittedly, I haven't used straight up Debian in as long either until recently.

Comment: Does `stty -a` show `^_` being assigned to any setting? Does `bind -p | grep '\\C-_'` list it as anything else than "undo"? Does `loadkeys --default` fix the problem?

Comment: No on stty assignment, bind shows C-_ being bound to undo, loadkeys --default just reads from from stdin. I thought the C-_ binding would be a good replacement for C-/, but unfortunately it's bound to zoom out on gnome-terminal so I can't use it everywhere either.